# var a= true if (x === 'condition') - it is similar to a ternary, but more like plain english. Is this valid javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
var a = true if x === 'condition'
```

I came across this in javascript and I never saw it before.
Is this.. err.. proper javascript? Where does it come from? It does seem to work.. Thanks!

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if"

Comment: When I run it in the console, it says there's a syntax error, so I'd say it's not valid syntax

Comment: *"It does seem to work"* I'm curious how you ran it...?

Comment: `a = true if x == 'condition'` would have been valid CoffeeScript *(RIP)*

Comment: Someone offered it as a js syntax to use instead of var `a = (x === 'condition') ? true : false;` I tried running it in a node.js application where i was getting data from an api and serving it back to my application to use in a template.. somehow the syntax worked (i.e. it gave correct results) and there were no errors output in terminal when it was running. But it seemed odd that I had never come across the syntax before and googling didn't bring anything up. hence the question

Comment: @user3407362 - *"Someone offered it as a js syntax to use instead of `var a = (x === 'condition') ? true : false;`"* Neither of those is a good way to do that. Instead, you do this: `var a = x === 'condition';`. `===` *already* returns a boolean, there's no need for the conditional operator there (and of course, the "alternative" isn't one, not in JavaScript [Python has something like it, though]).

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder - and good point. I have indeed updated the ternary to use `a = x === 'condition'`, I was mainly curious about the other syntax as I'd never seen it anywhere. It turns out she picked it up from a similar ruby syntax and got confused between languages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you got [pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) which can be written in JavaScript like this:

```
var a = x === 'condition'
```

That pseudo code states a will be true if x === 'condition', otherwise a will be false.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's invalid JavaScript, it results in a SyntaxError:

```js
var a = true if x === 'condition'
```

It has several problems:

- No `;` after `true`, and there's no line break so automatic semicolon insertion won't take effect, so there's a SyntaxError as of the `if`
- No `()` around the `if` statement's condition, so if you fix the above, there's a SyntaxError as of the `x` after `if`
- No body on the `if` statement, so if you fix the two items above, there's a SyntaxError at the end of the code

It also has a runtime problem:

- No declaration of `x`, so trying to read its value will result in a ReferenceError